# SMTP connect() failed. PHPMailer (GMAIL)

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, mailer

Hello i create code for send to email using php mailer in localhost
but i have a problem, this error is : **Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

This is my code

```
<?php 
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

        $from_email      = "gumay0838@gmail.com";
        $from_email_pwd  = "qwerty147";
        $from_email_name = "Gumay";
        $to_email        = "bedhoel.inc@gmail.com";

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = 'Hello World';
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);                  

$mail->IsSMTP();                                         // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                               // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";                    // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                                 // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = $from_email;                         // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = $from_email_pwd;                     // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom($from_email, $from_email_name);

$mail->Subject    = "Testing Mail";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress($to_email, $from_email);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
   ?>
```

Note :

im already active 
extension=php_openssl.dll  in php.ini

and already restart my xampp and already setting my gmail to Allow less secure apps: ON

Comment: Add `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` for debugging.

Comment: Add $mail->SMTPDebug  = 4; for debug notes

Comment: @RPicheta This error  > http://pastebin.com/sfudCSJu

Comment: @simon thank's  bro, message sent

Comment: try ssl instead of tls on port 465

Comment: Maybe this answer will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227702/php-mailer-error?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: It's failing at the point it starts TLS, so you have a TLS problem, and diagnosing what that is is covered in the troubleshooting guide the error links to. I would guess at an outdated or missing CA file.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40439333/3597276