# PHPMailer cannot send via smtp.gmail.com

Tags: iis, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mail with PHPMailer plugin via smtp.gmail.com. The sending works fine on my local computer but when I use my remote server with following code it delays the sending, normally around 30 seconds.

```
function sendAuthEmail($subject, $mail_body, $mailTo, $mailToTitle, $mailFrom, $fromTitle)
{
    require 'PhpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    $mail->Username = 'no-reply@domail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';

    $mail->AddReplyTo($mailFrom, $fromTitle);
    $mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, 'Domain.com');

    $mail->AddAddress($mailTo, $mailToTitle);

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($mail_body);

    if($mail->Send()) {
        return;
    } else {
        die('There was an error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo.'</i>');
    }
}
```

But when I try to use gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com') it fails with following debug information:

```
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a47sm16079918qtc.17 - gsmtp 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.sellercloud.com 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [199.189.62.92] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
2016-11-23 12:36:11 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40457245/3597276

Comment: @michael_b I remember trying this but I'll check again

Comment: @Michael_B I've tried again. It works on localhost but not on remote server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the server turned out to be a DNS resolving issue. PHP mailer couldn't resolve smtp.gmail.com correctly, and this was the main reason why none of the known fixes worked.

If you're having similar issue, **check your DNS servers**.