# PHPMailer | (mail from) Sender not allowed

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a contact form made using PHPMailer. It has been working since today, then it suddenly stopped working. I tried to understand why and I discovered I get everytime error about the sender which is not allowed as it says. Here is the code:

```
try {

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtps.aruba.it';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
  $mail->Username = 'info@mydomain.it'; 
  $mail->Password = 'myPassword';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
  $mail->Port = 587;
  
  $mail->setFrom("myemail@gmail.com", 'Sender'); // Here is where I put the sender email

  $mail->addAddress('info@mydomain.it');
  $mail->isHTML(true); 
  $mail->Subject = "Subject";  
  $mail->Body    = "Body";

  if (!$mail->send()) { 
    $result = array('status'=>"error", 'message'=>"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);//
    print_r(json_encode($result));

  } else {
    $result = array('status'=>"success", 'message'=>"Message sent.");
    print_r(json_encode($result));

  }
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error excpetion: ".$e;
}
```

Here is the error I get from the debug:

**The following From address failed: myemail@gmail.com: MAIL FROM command
failed,<myemail@gmail.com> ik2dozQHmuz2mik2doPsAn - Mittente non
consentito / Sender not allowed ( mail from )**

I tried to update PHPMailer, now I have the latest version. Also, I tried with an outlook.it email I have, but same error again.
It was perfectly working since today, can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand. Your code says the sender is `info@mydomain.it` yet your error says the sender is `myemail@gmail.com`. I can understand that *aruba.it* doesn't allow you to send from domains they don't host.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hi and thank you! The email where I should receive everything is 'info@mydomain.it' while 'myemail@gmail.com' is the one I am trying to use in the form, which I am putting inside the 'setFrom()' function.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see that now. Still, I would expect you to only be able to use `smtps.aruba.it` for sender addresses with domains that they host. Otherwise they would allow you to spoof any email address. And given the current state of emailing, even if they tried to forward the email, there would be a great change that the receiving mailserver would reject it. To put it bluntly: Aruba.it isn't Gmail.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Do you know why it has been working since today for more than one year? Thanks for your reply, but I'd like to ask what should I do now, is there something in the code that I should modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the server admin has applied anti email spoofing policy today, so yesterday it works, but today it disallows you to send thru smtps.aruba.it as
sender 'xxxxx@gmail.com'

The proper way is to change your "from" address to info@mydomain.it, but if you want the recipient to reply your email but get it sent to xxxxx@gmail.com, then add the following

```
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'your name in gmail');
```

Alternatively, use gmail smtp server to send out the email thru PHPMailer
(you may refer to the official link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en for the smtp settings needed)

In case you have other problems in using gmail smtp, you may also wish to refer to this SO post (or other related ones)

[PHPMailer does not work with Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439333/phpmailer-does-not-work-with-gmail-smtp)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much because now I receive the email. But there is the possibility to receive the email from the actual sender? This is not so much important but I would like to try anyway. Also, I went in my personal gmail and there was not the automatic reply, how can I fix this?

Comment: Normally the user will submit a form so that it goes thru your SMTP server smtps.aruba.it and send to you (thru PHPMailer in your case). So if you want to get the email from the actual sender you will need the user to enter his/her email address in the form and then submit this piece of information to you. (but of course we cannot guarantee that the user has entered a true email address, unless you further verify it say thru other authentication methods such as asking the user to click a link in a verification email)